# Generate random numbers in a specific order (conform to an equation) to produce a range of specific results

Tags: excel, matrix

I want to generate random numbers in a matrix (2x2) in order to produce a specific range of results. Particularly the result "Determinant" must be one of the following:

(1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 or 11 or 13 or 15 or 17 or 19 or 21 or 23 or 25)

and obey this equation:

```
(RandomA x RandomY)-(RandomB x RandomZ)=one of the aforementioned Range of the "Determinant"
```

(From left to right):

A is the first cell in the first row of the matrix.
B is the second cell in the first row of the matrix.
Z is the first cell in the second row of the matrix.
Y is the second cell in the second row of the matrix.

In other Words: I want when I click "Calculate Now" to give four random numbers -in the matrix- that produce one of the above-mentioned results every time randomly.

Comment: Do the numbers have to be integers? What are the lower and upper limits?

Comment: Surely genetate random numbers in an order makes them not random

Comment: Yahya05sy, if you're willing to do this programmatically, I believe @Gary'sStudent's answer is the way to go. If you need a solution that doesn't involve programming, just let us know (not saying that it's possible, but I've got some ideas and I could give it a try).

Comment: @EdHeal, I don't think Yahya05sy meant that A, B, Z and Y should produce a determinant that's 1, then 3, then 5 etc **in this specific order**. They need to be assigned a random value so as to always produce a determinant that has **any value** within this range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt something like:

```
Sub Yahya()
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   Dim detDesired As Long
   result = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25)
   Dim A1 As Range, A2 As Range, B1 As Range, B2 As Range, C3 As Range
   Set A1 = Range("A1")
   Set A2 = Range("A2")
   Set B1 = Range("B1")
   Set B2 = Range("B2")
   Set C3 = Range("C3")

   detDesired = result(wf.RandBetween(0, 12))
   C3 = detDesired
   A1 = wf.RandBetween(1, 20)
   B1 = wf.RandBetween(-10, 10)
   A2 = wf.RandBetween(-10, 10)

   B2 = (C3 + A2 * B1) / A1

End Sub
```

we are storing the determinant in **C3**.  Adjust the domains of the random picks to suit your needs:

[image]

The approach is to randomly pick the determinant and three of the four matrix elements; then calculate the fourth element *(as the problem is constrained)*